# How to set focusable a LinearLayout in touch mode?

Tags: android

How to set a LinearLayout `focusable` in touch mode?

I tried this:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

also this:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

But these dont work.What to do?
Thanks in advance.

Regards
Goutom

Comment: do you have used android:focusable="false"

Answer (score 4):

`android:focusable="true"  android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`  and remain the linear layout to be clickable true by default,,,   as per mentioned senario both the things are contradictory,..